# how to convert specific characters into string

Tags: python, base64, decode

I'm wondering how to convert those type of characters into a string: \x0b , \0x07.

To be clear, I'm using the base64 to decode a stream and then we will get those special characters. so my question is how to correct this code so I can get something correct:

```
encodedStr = 'somestring coded in base64'
missing_padding = 4 - len(encodedStr) % 4
if missing_padding:
    encodedStr += '=' * missing_padding
decodedBytes = base64.b64decode(encodedStr)
decodedStr = base64.b64decode(decodedBytes).decode('utf-8')
print(decodedBytes)
```

Comment: are you asking to only decode certain byte representations or?

Comment: Base 64 returns `bytes`; if those bytes represent text, you have to know the encoding. Trivially, try `decodedBytes.decode()` but if that doesn't work, you probably have to provide more details about what the contents are supposed to represent; perhaps see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: well, if I remove the line 6, I will only get something like: \xdf\xcd..., I want to be able to read them. So I removed the line 6 because I got an error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid

Comment: @tripleee, I got an error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Comment: For what it's worth [U+000B](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/index.htm) (vertical tab) and [U+0007](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0007/index.htm) (audible bell) are ASCII control characters which do not typically have a printable representation.

Comment: Well then see the linked meta question about how to ask an actually well-defined question about character encodings. But probably the reason the data you received was base64-encoded is simply that it does not correspond to anything human-readable.

Comment: The duplicate is approximate at best, but should provide a set of good answers for why arbitrary binary data cannot meaningfully be converted to text. If that's not what you are asking, please [edit] to clarify.